# Add external guest to Microsoft Teams existing group via Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've tried this for so long and the Microsoft Documentation about inviting guests to time with javascript isn't really that clear either, so here goes my problem:

We have existing Teams where users can add external guests to their team via an external website, we have the TenantID, GroupId and UserId of the person who wants to invite and the e-mail address of the guest.

I can get a valid accessToken from the app via the following way:

```
const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tenantId+"/oauth2/v2.0/token";
const requestParams = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: "xx",
    client_secret: "xx",
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    requested_token_use: "on_behalf_of",
};

request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
  const accessToken = parsedBody.access_token;
  // returns a valid accessToken
});
```

But anything past this doesn't work.
Can anyone provide me some javascript samples on how to add external guests?

Comment: Looks like a similar question raised [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/76273/adding-external-users-to-teams-using-graph-api-or.html).

Comment: This would not be possible for us, we're working as an app under a tenant and cannot access the credentials for this

Comment: Have you tried the [invitation endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)? See if this works for your scenario.